# Is it possible to create a bitmask for ~100 constants?

Tags: java, primitive-types, bitmask

Would that mean that the 100th constant would have to be 1 << 100?

Comment: `long` (the largest integer primitive in Java) only has 64 bits. So, no: not with a *single* primitive value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it directly because maximum size for a primitive number which can be used as a bitmask is actually 64 bit for a `long` value. What you can do is to split the bitmask into 2 or more `int`s or `long`s and then manage it by hand.

```
int[] mask = new int[4];
final int MAX_SHIFT = 32;

void set(int b) {
  mask[b / MAX_SHIFT] |= 1 << (b % MAX_SHIFT);
}

boolean isSet(int b) {
  return (mask[b / MAX_SHIFT] & (1 << (b % MAX_SHIFT))) != 0;
}
```

Comment: unless the miracles out and optimizes div and mod into right shift / bitwise and... the cost would be quite higher compared to the aforementioned operations. Div/Mod is one of the most expensive operations for the CPUs that doesn't involve bus/coherency/cache misses.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a BitSet which has any number bits you want to set or clear. e.g.

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(101);
bitSet.set(100);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only create a simple bitmask with the number of bits in the primitive type.

If you have a 32 bit (as in normal Java) int then 1 << 31 is the most you can shift the low bit.

To have larger constants you use an array of int elements and you figure out which array element to use by dividing by 32 (with 32 bit int) and shift with % 32 (modula) into the selected array element.

Answer (score 2):

Effective Java Item #32 suggests using an [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead of bit fields. Internally, it uses a bit vector so it is efficient, however, it becomes more readable as each bit has a descriptive name (the enum constant).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you intend to be able to bitwise OR any or all of those constants together, then you're going to need a bit representing each constant. Of course if you use an `int` you will only have 32 bits and a `long` will only give you 64 bits.